# How to publish dot net Windows application programmatically?

Tags: c#, publish, build-automation

Instead of click publish button and choose path,i need to publish the application programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [dotnet publish](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish) command.

> dotnet publish - Publishes the application and its dependencies to a folder for deployment to a hosting system.